# Get map center point on scrolling Google maps v2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-mapview

Hi iam doing an app very in my app there is a map page so i implemented Google Maps V2 and i have a issue i when i scroll the map i want to get the center points of the map that is if i scroll the map and i leave it then it gets the center points of the map so can any one can suggest to solve this issue it may be helpful Thank you in advance.......

**Note** : I have Used a Google Maps V2 so please post related to that .

```
public class Mapview extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener, OnCameraChangeListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;
Location myLocation;
TextView tvLocInfo;
GPSTracker gps;
public double Latitude,Longitude;
String Datetime, addr,RegUID;
public String lat,longd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    Projection P = myMap.getProjection();
    Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(Latitude));
    Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    Button mDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);         
    mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "latitude"+lat+""+"longitude"+longd , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());                
            Datetime = timeStamp.toString();
            Log.e("t", Datetime);               
            RegUID = Utils.RegisterUserId;
            Log.e("t", RegUID);
            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Mapview.this, "", Utils.Loading, true);
            dialog.show();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI = Utils.Request+"UserID="+RegUID+"&Location="+URLEncoder.encode(addr,"UTF-8")+"&Latitude="+lat+"&Longitude="+longd+"&RequestDate="+URLEncoder.encode(Datetime,"UTF-8");
                        Log.e(EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI, EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI);
                        JSONObject JObject = Utils.getResult(EMPLOYEE_SERVICE_URI);
                        //Toast.makeText(Mapview.this,JObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(JObject!=null)
                        {     

                            if(JObject.getBoolean("Valid"))
                            {

                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mapview.this).create();
                                Utils.callAlert(JObject.getString("Message"), alertDialog);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mapview.this).create();
                                Utils.callAlert(JObject.getString("Message"), alertDialog);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mapview.this).create();
                            Utils.callAlert(JObject.getString("Message"), alertDialog);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(Mapview.this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }//run() ends  
            }, 5000);               


        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.i("test","onScroll");
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(point.latitude));
    Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(point.longitude));
    Latitude =point.latitude;
    Longitude = point.longitude;
    lat = String.valueOf(point.latitude);
    longd = String.valueOf(point.longitude);        
    myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
    gps = new GPSTracker(Mapview.this);
    // check if GPS enabled     
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {   

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(Latitude, Longitude, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");  
                }
                addr = new String(strReturnedAddress);
                tvLocInfo.setText(addr.toString());

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), addr.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps location address is unavailable please try again later",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:-

```
myMap.setOnCameraChangedListener(this);
```

And in the listener:-

```
onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    LatLng target = position.target;
    // do what you need with the position here
}
```

I'm not sure about the index out of bounds. But to set a default map position you could use something like below:-

```
    private void setDefaultMapPosition(LatLng latLng) {

    CameraPosition camPos =
            new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng)
            .zoom(A_DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM)
            .bearing(0)
            .tilt(0)
            .build();

    myMap.moveCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));

   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ....... i have a issue that when i open map it's showing `LatLang (0.0,0.0) `and forcible closing the app with error Index out of bond...

Comment: Very nice explained.

Answer (score 2):

The interface `OnCameraChangeListener` has been deprecated. You can now use now `OnCameraIdleListener`

> Called when camera movement has ended, there are no pending animations
>   and the user has stopped interacting with the map.

and fetch the coordinates of the center by doing:

```kotlin
val centerCoordinates = mMap.cameraPosition.target
```